# Improving update performance in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, database-performance

I have 2 tables in Access:

```
tbl_RM: (+ for primary key)
  + CustomerName (short text)
  + CountryCode  (short text)
  + RMDate       (Date/Time - format mmm-yy)
  + SerialNumber (short text)
    BlackClicks  (Double)
    ColorClicks  (Double)
    AccentClicks (Double)
    ProfessionalColorClicks (Double)
```

The second table

```
tbl_Invoices: (+ for primary key)
  + CustomerName (short text)
  + CountryCode  (short text)
  + InvoiceDate  (Date/Time)
  + SerialNumber (short text)
    BlackClicks  (Double)
    ColorClicks  (Double)
```

tbl_RM contains 98 496 records (out of which 9113 match the query below)

tbl_Invoices contains 9 618 records (all matching the below request).

I want to update tbl_Invoices with data from tbl_RM. here is my update query:

```
UPDATE tbl_Invoices
INNER JOIN tbl_RM 
      ON tbl_Invoices.CustomerName = tbl_RM.CustomerName
      AND tbl_Invoices.CountryCode = tbl_RM.CountryCode
      AND tbl_Invoices.SerialNumber = tbl_RM.SerialNumber
      AND MONTH(tbl_RM.RMDate) = MONTH(tbl_Invoices.InvoiceDate)
      AND YEAR(tbl_RM.RMDate) = YEAR(tbl_Invoices.InvoiceDate)
SET tbl_Invoices.BlackPages =  tbl_RM.BlackClicks + tbl_RM.AccentClicks,
tbl_Invoices.ColorPages =  tbl_RM.ColorClicks + tbl_RM.ProfessionalColorClicks
```

When running this in ACCESS 2013 it takes hours to compute. I guess there is a way to speed that up. Any suggestion will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first suggestion is an index on `tbl_RM(CustomerName, CountryCode SerialNumber)`.  The might be good enough.  If that is not then you might need to handle the dates in the index as well.